# AutoSuggestBox behaves differently if AcceptsReturn is True for the textbox inside its style

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a simple `AutoSuggestBox` with its style modified by changing few properties of `TextBox` within it.
The properties i have modified where `AcceptsReturn` and `MinHeight`

Here's the modified Portion of the style

```
<Style TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
  <!-- -->
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" Canvas.ZIndex="0" MinHeight="20" Margin="0" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />

  <!-- -->
</Style>
```

**Here my complete sample code**

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApplication.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" Canvas.ZIndex="0" MinHeight="20" Margin="0" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
                            <Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">
                                <Border x:Name="SuggestionsContainer">
                                    <ListView x:Name="SuggestionsList" Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBorderBrush}" DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" MaxHeight="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMaxHeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMargin}" Padding="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListPadding}" />
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>   
    <StackPanel>
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="MyAutoSuggestBox"  Margin="100" Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

[Here's Sample GiF of What happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNE9J.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/text-box#enable-multi-line-input), it mentions we typically set the **AcceptsReturn** and **TextWrapping** properties to make a multi-line text box. So you can add TextWrapping property like below.

And if you don't want to add TextWrapping property, you can set a value to Text in `Page.Loaded` event. When the AutoSuggestBox has loaded and assign to the Text property, it works well.

```
<Style TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
  <!-- -->
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="20" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" Canvas.ZIndex="0" Margin="0" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />

  <!-- -->
</Style>
```